# Helios: How to protect with a password

Tags: ruby, security, rack

Seems like anyone knowing your URL would stick it a /admin and be able to spam your users ;) How would you prevent that?

Comment: Ask their support, this is off topic here

Comment: Obviously I didn't ask already....... ?! (#facepalm)

Answer (score 1):

Found here: http://recipes.sinatrarb.com/p/middleware/rack_auth_basic_and_digest

```
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require

use Rack::Auth::Basic, "Protected Area" do |username, password|
  username == 'foo' && password == 'bar'
end

app = Helios::Application.new {
  ...
}

run app
```

Comment: Hmmm... Basic Auth is... Basic :) Could be enough in some cases, but I just decided/realized it's no in mine. Another question is then how to have some routes public. Tried the examples at that website for that for now without luck.

Comment: Seems you are doing their support. +1 ;)

Comment: `require 'bundler'` `Bundler.require` This looks funny!

Comment: @hek2mgl — this is a standard Helios.io setup. Not sure why there's 2 require here :) oh and yes I'm doing there support because nobody answers when you ask questions to them :( which support? :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out for Basic Auth you can simple use those 2 Environment variables

```
HELIOS_ADMIN_USERNAME=foo
HELIOS_ADMIN_PASSWORD-bar
```

In dev it's as simple as a `.env` file in the root — which works awesome, but with Heroku I add to use `heroku config:set HELIOS_ADMIN_USERNAME=foo` (and still, it doesn't work, somehow)...